# info.magnolia.module.templating.RenderException: Can't find renderer for type null

Tags: magnolia

I have created an `empty webapp project` in eclipse  and added `magnolia STK` dependency to use it. I deploy the `empty webapp project` to the server using `tomcat`. Now I would like to create my `first page template` as descriped [here](http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS45/Introduction+to+templating). After creating the page, when I open the created page (in Website rightclick on hello.html -> open page), I get the following exception:

```
    2014-05-06 12:39:03,823 ERROR info.magnolia.module.templating.RenderingFilter   : Can't find renderer for type null
info.magnolia.module.templating.RenderException: Can't find renderer for type null
    at info.magnolia.module.templating.engine.DefaultRenderingEngine.render(DefaultRenderingEngine.java:167)
    at info.magnolia.module.templating.engine.DefaultRenderingEngine.render(DefaultRenderingEngine.java:130)
    at info.magnolia.module.templating.engine.DefaultRenderingEngine$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8879a547.render(<generated>)
    at info.magnolia.module.templating.RenderingFilter.render(RenderingFilter.java:137)
    at info.magnolia.module.templating.RenderingFilter.doFilter(RenderingFilter.java:92)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.BackwardCompatibilityFilter.doFilter(BackwardCompatibilityFilter.java:73)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:60)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.module.templating.ModelExecutionFilter.doFilter(ModelExecutionFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:60)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.InterceptFilter.doFilter(InterceptFilter.java:121)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AggregatorFilter.doFilter(AggregatorFilter.java:104)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.security.BaseSecurityFilter.doFilter(BaseSecurityFilter.java:64)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.RepositoryMappingFilter.doFilter(RepositoryMappingFilter.java:91)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:66)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:76)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:66)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.VirtualUriFilter.doFilter(VirtualUriFilter.java:69)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.module.cache.executor.Bypass.processCacheRequest(Bypass.java:57)
    at info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:147)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:60)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.i18n.I18nContentSupportFilter.doFilter(I18nContentSupportFilter.java:75)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.GZipFilter.doFilter(GZipFilter.java:73)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:60)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)
    at info.magnolia.cms.security.BaseSecurityFilter.doFilter(BaseSecurityFilter.java:64)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.security.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:60)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.security.auth.login.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:77)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CosMultipartRequestFilter.doFilter(CosMultipartRequestFilter.java:86)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:60)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContentTypeFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeFilter.java:102)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:120)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:66)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:105)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:216)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurreMai 06, 2014 12:39:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/magnolia-empty-webapp] threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: info.magnolia.module.templating.RenderException: Can't find renderer for type null
    at info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:159)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:60)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.i18n.I18nContentSupportFilter.doFilter(I18nContentSupportFilter.java:75)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.GZipFilter.doFilter(GZipFilter.java:73)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:60)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)
    at info.magnolia.cms.security.BaseSecurityFilter.doFilter(BaseSecurityFilter.java:64)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.security.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:60)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.security.auth.login.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:77)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CosMultipartRequestFilter.doFilter(CosMultipartRequestFilter.java:86)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:60)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContentTypeFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeFilter.java:102)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:120)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:66)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:105)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:216)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: info.magnolia.module.templating.RenderException: Can't find renderer for type null
    at info.magnolia.module.templating.RenderingFilter.doFilter(RenderingFilter.java:110)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.BackwardCompatibilityFilter.doFilter(BackwardCompatibilityFilter.java:73)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:60)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.module.templating.ModelExecutionFilter.doFilter(ModelExecutionFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:60)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.InterceptFilter.doFilter(InterceptFilter.java:121)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AggregatorFilter.doFilter(AggregatorFilter.java:104)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.security.BaseSecurityFilter.doFilter(BaseSecurityFilter.java:64)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.RepositoryMappingFilter.doFilter(RepositoryMappingFilter.java:91)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:66)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:76)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:66)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.VirtualUriFilter.doFilter(VirtualUriFilter.java:69)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
    at info.magnolia.module.cache.executor.Bypass.processCacheRequest(Bypass.java:57)
    at info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(Cant.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
cheFilter.java:147)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: info.magnolia.module.templating.RenderException: Can't find renderer for type null
    at info.magnolia.module.templating.engine.DefaultRenderingEngine.render(DefaultRenderingEngine.java:167)
    at info.magnolia.module.templating.engine.DefaultRenderingEngine.render(DefaultRenderingEngine.java:130)
    at info.magnolia.module.templating.engine.DefaultRenderingEngine$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8879a547.render(<generated>)
    at info.magnolia.module.templating.RenderingFilter.render(RenderingFilter.java:137)
    at info.magnolia.module.templating.RenderingFilter.doFilter(RenderingFilter.java:92)
    ... 88 more
```

Mybe is the problem that I set the type of the `freemarker` as `String`?? but there is only the 4 types see the attached [image: picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In the tutorial mentioned before the `type` is called `renderType`. Replacing `renderType` with `type` solved it

Answer (score 1):

renderType has to be "stk" if you use this for your tenplates